# How to properly redirect to the same page in php

Tags: php

I am working on something that i want to use in a project.
i am to redirect the current page to itself using php and session. The idea is that:

```
if my `$_session['insert']= true; then refresh the page to itself;`
```

Here is the code:

```
sess_page1.php
session_start();
$_SESSION["insert"] = 1;
$_SESSION["test"] = "Page refreshed";
?>
<a href="sess_page2.php">Click here</a> to go to the next page

sess_page2.php

<?php
session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION["insert"]) && ($_SESSION["insert"]==1)) {
header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

print $_SESSION["test"];
 }
   else
   {
    echo "Impossible to execute.";
    exit();
   }
?>
```

But the page does not redirect to itself...The whole idea is the page should refresh one time.

What i did wrong here? Can somebody help?

Comment: Is this all one file, or two? It looks like `sess_page2.php` is declared in the middle of html. The html link `<a href="sess_page2.php">` goes to a file called `sess_page2.php`. The `if` block is checked immediately on loading the page, so it fails. It's not waiting for the click.

Comment: It looks like your code does refresh itself when it goes to page2, but it doesn't unset the `$_SESSION['insert']` variable so it goes into an infinite loop. You should do `unset($_SESSION['insert']);` after you do `print $_SESSION["test"];`

Comment: @Tim I am assuming he meant 2 pages and the `sess_page2.php` is just labeling the second page.

Comment: @Tim Yes that is the point...sess_page1.php is first page and sess_page2.php is the second page

Comment: Sorry, I hate that SO shows that as one block.

Comment: You will have a redirect loop with that code.

Comment: @monace19 could you advise how i can achieve my goal then?

Comment: @Afrik Developeur check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sess_page1.php


session_start();
$_SESSION["stopper"] = 0;
$_SESSION["insert"] = 1;
$_SESSION["test"] = "Page refreshed";
?>
<a href="sess_page2.php">Click here</a> to go to the next page

sess_page2.php

<?php
session_start();
 if (isset($_SESSION["insert"]) && ($_SESSION["insert"]==1) && ($_SESSION["stopper"]==0)) {
     $_SESSION['stopper']=1;
     header('location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

     print $_SESSION["test"];
 } 
   else
   {
    echo "Impossible to execute.";
    exit();
   }
?>
```

Comment: You could remove the else statement and echo $_SESSION["test"]; because after it refresh, it will execute the else statement since $_SESSION["stopper"] would be equal to 1.